# What kind of tree is in my yard with red stems, ribbed oval leaves, and white flowers?

Tags: trees

This tree is in my yard with red stems, ribbed oval leaves, and white flowers

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is *Viburnum plicatum*,a deciduous shrub sometimes mistaken for a lacecap type of Hydrangea because of the flower form.  https://plantcaretoday.com/viburnum-plicatum.html